# como insertar un dataset a un gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estoy intentado un `DataSet` a un `GridView`. Me he guiado con algunos ejemplos de internet

Esta es parte code behind y al ejecutarlo me muestra el siguiente error:

> Fill: la propiedad SelectCommand.Connection no se ha inicializado.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack) {
        refresh();
    }
}

public void refresh() 
{
    string connectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cadenaConexionAlumnos"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from carrera");
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet dsCarrera = new DataSet();
    sda.Fill(dsCarrera);
    GVCarrera.DataSource = dsCarrera;
    GVCarrera.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Buenas pipeRos,

Te falta indicar que conexión va a usar el `SqlCommand`, prueba así:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from carrera", con);
```